# How rolled log files in Tomcat 6/7?

Tags: tomcat, logging

I know that Tomcat uses JULI logger. Does it possible to set file size limit?
I see that files are rolled in some way, but where this parameter is set I cannot figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logging is configured in `/conf/logging.properties` in your tomcat root.

JULI filehandler rolls files each day, as described in javadoc of 'rotatable' property here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/FileHandler.html .

I don't think it's possible to set a size limit for log file in JULI, but you can switch the logging framework used to Log4J (description how to do so can be found here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html) and then you can use RollingFileAppender which has an option for maximum file size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Log4j - which is fine - but all this is based upon the java.util.logging structure.  You can replace all the instances with the 'juli' FileHandler with the java.util.logging.FileHandler.  It allows for log sizes and number of files to keep:

- java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit specifies an approximate maximum
  amount to write (in bytes) to any one file. If this is zero, then
  there is no limit. (Defaults to no limit).
- java.util.logging.FileHandler.count specifies how many output files
  to cycle through (defaults to 1).

Answer (score 1):

When running Tomcat on Linux the rotation of (system) log files can be handled by logrotate. In my Ubuntu (14.0.4 LTS) this is configured by default to rotate tomcat logs daily (when not empty). At most 7 log files are kept and rotated log files are compressed. The exact (default) configuration is found here *(Note that using ubuntu [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) is responsible for managing services like tomcat)*:

```
/etc/logrotate.d/upstart
```

The content is

```
/var/log/upstart/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 7
        compress
        notifempty
        nocreate
}
```

To rotate when log file exceeds a specified size this can be configured using the **size** e.g. `size 100k` as specified in the manpage [logrotate(8)](https://linuxconfig.org/logrotate-8-manual-page)